# Webbrowser component behind TpopUpMenu does not respond

Tags: delphi, vcl, popupmenu

I am using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and the VCL component from TMS Software named `WebOSMaps`. That component uses a `TWebBrowser` component to display a map with several markers on it.

Over a marker I use a `TPopupMenu` to display my own menu. My problem is, if the PopupMenu is open, there is no interaction with other components on that Form, like `OnMouseOver` or `OnClick`. If I right-click on another position of that `TWebBrowser`, the `TPopupMenu` shows up again, but with the same information as before, because of there is no interaction with the `OnMouseDown` event of the `TWebBrowser`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You do know that a TPopupMenu holds focus when active? I'm not sure I understand what the information is that you expect to see on the second right click. If you can replicate the problem with VCL components only, please provide a [mcve]. If your problem only occurs with the TMS components, it might be better ask the provider of those components.

Comment: Menu loops are modal, which means that while the menu is open all activity within the application goes to that menu. If you're trying to do anything else while the menu is active, you're doing something against the design of Windows itself, and that doesn't usually work out well.

Comment: If your TPopupMenu contents is dependant on the point of the WebOSMap you're right clicking, look into the TPopupMenu.OnPopUp event and populate your menu on that event instead of relying of MouseMove/MouseDown events of the TWebBrowser.